# Android and sticky session

Tags: android, amazon-elb, sticky-session

I have an Android application that sends requests to servers behind an elb.

Unfortunately, sticky session doesn't seem to be take in account (automatically) by Android unlike iOS.

What is the solution/best practice to do this with Android ?

Answer (score 1):

You should save the token or whatever value you use to identify the user in the a persistent storage (more info here : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage). After the app restarts it can load the token to the requests sent to the server.

I would personally go with SharedPreference (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#pref) with encryption of the token to prevent retrieval of the token by any third party (which can happen on a rooted or otherwise tampered with device).

Good luck!